# Quarkus rest reactive endpoint throws read timeout

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-reactive

We have an application based in Quarkus framework which exposes an REST endpoint.
This endpoint accepts a big json payload every 5mins (~1mb). Sometimes we could see these errors which I pasted below. When the client retries, it works properly.

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.ServerJacksonMessageBodyReader.readFrom(ServerJacksonMessageBodyReader.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.ServerJacksonMessageBodyReader.readFrom(ServerJacksonMessageBodyReader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RequestDeserializeHandler.readFrom(RequestDeserializeHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RequestDeserializeHandler.handle(RequestDeserializeHandler.java:81)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Read timed out (through reference chain: com.test.StockReport["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[9037])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:402)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:373)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:375)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1481)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.ServerJacksonMessageBodyReader.doReadFrom(ServerJacksonMessageBodyReader.java:87)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.ServerJacksonMessageBodyReader.readFrom(ServerJacksonMessageBodyReader.java:38)
    ... 12 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Read timed out
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream$VertxBlockingInput.readBlocking(VertxInputStream.java:255)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream.readIntoBuffer(VertxInputStream.java:122)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream.close(VertxInputStream.java:150)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._closeInput(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:291)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.close(ParserBase.java:386)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2112)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read timed out
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream$VertxBlockingInput.readBlocking(VertxInputStream.java:237)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream.readIntoBuffer(VertxInputStream.java:122)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream.read(VertxInputStream.java:84)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:257)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseEscapedName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2101)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.slowParseName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2009)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parseName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1797)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:797)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:359)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2105)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.io.IOException: Read timed out]
```

The log traces shows the error message originates from line 239.

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/vertx-http/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/vertx/http/runtime/VertxInputStream.java

The server request for a connection to establish but it is getting timed out.

**Read timeout?**
Initially, I thought the problem was the client closes the connection before the server process the request, I tried to reproduce with using curl command and closes the connection before the server process the request, the error message is quite different than the above one, and cannot able to reproduce the same error message.

Error message when client closes the connection.
Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.io.IOException: io.vertx.core.http.HttpClosedException: Connection was closed]

Question?

1. what could be the reason for this read timeout problem?
2. Why the message is showing "CIRCULAR REFERENCE" when the connection was closed by client? it is bit misleading.

I found the reason for issue#1 the time out value for the inputstream is hardcoded.

````
public InputStream createInputStream() { 
if (context.getBody() != null) { 
byte[] data = new byte[context.getBody().length()]; context.getBody().getBytes(data); 
return new ByteArrayInputStream(data); } 
return new VertxInputStream(context, 10000, this); 
} ```
````

Comment: Hello, I believe you are searching for the wrong source of the problem. It seems your read time out is due to a CIRCULAR REFERENCE (at the end of your stacktrace). I believe jackson is trying to serialize an entity containing bi directional relation. We would need to see your code or minimal reproducer to better understand what you are trying to do, please edit your question.

Comment: @jacouille the json payload we use is very simple and straight forward. When retried with same payload it works properly. it is definitely NOT the circular reference problem...the error message displayed it bit misleading.

Comment: I understand very well, but from experience "very simple and straight forward" is what you expect, not what you actually get. You didn't not expect Circular Reference but that's what you get. Either you find why it rises, or you ignore it and try guessing what could be happening (ignoring stacktrace). Add example of json and code that uses it to your question, otherwise it'll be impossible to help you.

Comment: @jacouille I have made a simple reproducer in github https://github.com/vigneshsn/quarkus-reative   , in the last section of read me you can find the curl command which reproduce the issue. You could see in logs Circular reference problem even though the reason of the problem is client closing the connection.

Comment: Can you open an issue on Github for this? It seems like a bug...

Comment: @geoand also I see the reason this read timeout is the hardcoded timeout value i  VerxtResteasyRectiveRequestContext.java. I see for some of the request the server takes more time to read from InputStream and eventually endup in read timeout.@Override
    public InputStream createInputStream() {
        if (context.getBody() != null) {
            byte[] data = new byte[context.getBody().length()];
            context.getBody().getBytes(data);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }
        return new VertxInputStream(context, 10000, this);
    }

Comment: Yeah, we should fix that